# Kusto - Add percentage symbol to the result

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto Query to calculate a percentage value.
for example `percentage = 100 * online / total`
then I output the result with `| project perc`

But I could not add the percentage symbol to the values in the table. COuld you please suggest how to resolve for example the value should be 100% instead of just 100

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `strcat()` function.

For example: `print p = strcat(100, "%")`

Comment: I was able to resolve . I included the function in the calculation. Thanks.

```| extend p =strcat(round(100 * online / total),"%")```